# I keep getting this error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'videos_slug_unique'what do I do to fix it

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a site I created that has a blog section and a video section. I had a config file for blog that I tried to share with the video section but it wasn't working properly so I created a separate config for video. and modified my column names for video from

```
    $title and $subtitle
```

to

```
    $v_title and $v_subtitle.
```

but when I do I get the following error

```
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'videos_slug_unique'
```

for some reason a slug is not being produced and this causes the issue. The slug is unique in my table. If I change the variables to how they were

```
    $title and $subtitle
```

it works, why is that?

this is my Admin videoController

```
    <?php

        namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

        use App\Jobs\VideoFormFields;
        use App\Http\Requests;
        use App\Http\Requests\VideoCreateRequest;
        use App\Http\Requests\VideoUpdateRequest;
        use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
        use App\Video;

        class VideoController extends Controller
        {
            /**
             * Display a listing of the posts.
             */
            public function index()
            {
                return view('admin.video.index')
                    ->withVideos(Video::all());
            }

            /**
             * Show the new video form
             */
            public function create()
            {
                $data = $this->dispatch(new VideoFormFields());

                return view('admin.video.create', $data);
            }

            /**
             * Store a newly created Video
             *
             * @param VideoCreateRequest $request
             */
            public function store(VideoCreateRequest $request)
            {
                $video = Video::create($request->videoFillData());
                $video->syncTags($request->get('tags', []));

                return redirect()
                    ->route('admin.video.index')
                    ->withSuccess('New Video Successfully Created.');
            }

            /**
             * Show the video edit form
             *
             * @param  int  $id
             * @return Response
             */
            public function edit($id)
            {
                $data = $this->dispatch(new VideoFormFields($id));

                return view('admin.video.edit', $data);
            }

            /**
             * Update the Video
             *
             * @param VideoUpdateRequest $request
             * @param int  $id
             */
            public function update(VideoUpdateRequest $request, $id)
            {
                $video = Video::findOrFail($id);
                $video->fill($request->videoFillData());
                $video->save();
                $video->syncTags($request->get('tags', []));

                if ($request->action === 'continue') {
                    return redirect()
                        ->back()
                        ->withSuccess('Video saved.');
                }

                return redirect()
                    ->route('admin.video.index')
                    ->withSuccess('Video saved.');
            }

            /**
             * Remove the specified resource from storage.
             *
             * @param  int  $id
             * @return Response
             */
            public function destroy($id)
            {
                $video = Video::findOrFail($id);
                $video->tags()->detach();
                $video->delete();

                return redirect()
                    ->route('admin.video.index')
                    ->withSuccess('Video deleted.');
            }
        }
```

this is my videoFormFields

```
    <?php

            namespace App\Jobs;

            use App\Video;
            use App\Tag;
            use Carbon\Carbon;
            use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

            class VideoFormFields extends Job implements SelfHandling
            {
                /**
                 * The id (if any) of the Post row
                 *
                 * @var integer
                 */
                protected $id;

                /**
                 * List of fields and default value for each field
                 *
                 * @var array
                 */
                protected $fieldList = [
                    'v_title' => '',
                    'v_subtitle' => '',
                    'page_image' => '',
                    'content' => '',
                    'meta_description' => '',
                    'is_draft' => "0",
                    'publish_date' => '',
                    'publish_time' => '',
                    'layout' => 'video.layouts.v_post',
                    'tags' => [],
                ];

                /**
                 * Create a new command instance.
                 *
                 * @param integer $id
                 */
                public function __construct($id = null)
                {
                    $this->id = $id;
                }

                /**
                 * Execute the command.
                 *
                 * @return array of fieldnames => values
                 */
                public function handle()
                {
                    $fields = $this->fieldList;

                    if ($this->id) {
                        $fields = $this->fieldsFromModel($this->id, $fields);
                    } else {
                        $when = Carbon::now()->addHour();
                        $fields['publish_date'] = $when->format('M-j-Y');
                        $fields['publish_time'] = $when->format('g:i A');
                    }

                    foreach ($fields as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
                        $fields[$fieldName] = old($fieldName, $fieldValue);
                    }

                    return array_merge(
                        $fields,
                        ['allTags' => Tag::lists('tag')->all()]
                    );
                }

                /**
                 * Return the field values from the model
                 *
                 * @param integer $id
                 * @param array $fields
                 * @return array
                 */
                protected function fieldsFromModel($id, array $fields)
                {
                    $video = Video::findOrFail($id);

                    $fieldNames = array_keys(array_except($fields, ['tags']));

                    $fields = ['id' => $id];
                    foreach ($fieldNames as $field) {
                        $fields[$field] = $video->{$field};
                    }

                    $fields['tags'] = $video->tags()->lists('tag')->all();

                    return $fields;
                }
            }
```

this is my videoCreateRequest

```
    <?php

            namespace App\Http\Requests;

            use Carbon\Carbon;

            class VideoCreateRequest extends Request
            {
                /**
                 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
                 */
                public function authorize()
                {
                    return true;
                }

                /**
                 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
                 *
                 * @return array
                 */
                public function rules()
                {
                    return [
                        'v_title' => 'required',
                        'v_subtitle' => 'required',
                        'content_raw' => 'required', //                                         HERE CHANGED
                        'publish_date' => 'required',
                        'publish_time' => 'required',
                        'layout' => 'required',
                    ];
                }

                /**
                 * Return the fields and values to create a new VIDEO post from
                 */
                public function videoFillData()
                {
                    $published_at = new Carbon(
                        $this->publish_date.' '.$this->publish_time
                    );
                    return [
                        'v_title' => $this->v_title,
                        'v_subtitle' => $this->v_subtitle,
                        'page_image' => $this->page_image,
                        'content_raw' => $this->content_raw, //                                  HERE CHANGED
                        'meta_description' => $this->meta_description,
                        'is_draft' => (bool)$this->is_draft,
                        'published_at' => $published_at,
                        'layout' => $this->layout,
                    ];
                }
            }
```

this is my videoUpdateRequest

```
            class VideoUpdateRequest extends VideoCreateRequest
            {
                //
            }
```

this is my video model

```
    <?php

            namespace App;

            use App\Services\Markdowner;
            use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
            use Carbon\Carbon;
            use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence;
            class Video extends Model
            {
                use Eloquence;

                protected $dates = ['published_at'];

                protected $fillable = [
                    'v_title', 'v_subtitle', 'content_raw', 'page_image', 'meta_description',
                    'layout', 'is_draft', 'published_at',
                ];

                /**
                 * The many-to-many relationship between posts and tags.
                 *
                 * @return BelongsToMany
                 */
                public function tags()
                {
                    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
                }

                /**
                 * Set the title attribute and automatically the slug
                 *
                 * @param string $value
                 */
                public function setTitleAttribute($value)
                {
                    $this->attributes['title'] = $value;

                    if (! $this->exists) {
                        $this->setUniqueSlug($value, '');
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Recursive routine to set a unique slug
                 *
                 * @param string $title
                 * @param mixed $extra
                 */
                protected function setUniqueSlug($title, $extra)
                {
                    $slug = str_slug($title.'-'.$extra);

                    if (static::whereSlug($slug)->exists()) {
                        $this->setUniqueSlug($title, $extra + 1);
                        return;
                    }

                    $this->attributes['slug'] = $slug;
                }

                /**
                 * Set the HTML content automatically when the raw content is set
                 *
                 * @param string $value
                 */
                public function setContentRawAttribute($value)
                {
                    $markdown = new Markdowner();

                    $this->attributes['content_raw'] = $value;
                    $this->attributes['content_html'] = $markdown->toHTML($value);
                }

                /**
                 * Sync tag relation adding new tags as needed
                 *
                 * @param array $tags
                 */
                public function syncTags(array $tags)
                {
                    Tag::addNeededTags($tags);

                    if (count($tags)) {
                        $this->tags()->sync(
                            Tag::whereIn('tag', $tags)->lists('id')->all()
                        );
                        return;
                    }

                    $this->tags()->detach();
                }

                /**
                 * Return the date portion of published_at
                 */
                public function getPublishDateAttribute($value)
                {
                    return $this->published_at->format('M-j-Y');
                }

                /**
                 * Return the time portion of published_at
                 */
                public function getPublishTimeAttribute($value)
                {
                    return $this->published_at->format('g:i A');
                }

                /**
                 * Alias for content_raw
                 */
                public function getContentAttribute($value)
                {
                    return $this->content_raw;
                }

                /**
                 * Return URL to post
                 *
                 * @param Tag $tag
                 * @return string
                 */
                public function url(Tag $tag = null)
                {
                    $url = url('video/'.$this->slug);  // this fixed my problem it was 'blog/'
                    if ($tag) {
                        $url .= '?tag='.urlencode($tag->tag);
                    }

                    return $url;
                }

                /**
                 * Return array of tag links
                 *
                 * @param string $base
                 * @return array
                 */
                public function tagLinks($base = '/video?tag=%TAG%') // this fixed my problem it was 'blog?tag=%TAG%/'
                {
                    $tags = $this->tags()->lists('tag');
                    $return = [];
                    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                        $url = str_replace('%TAG%', urlencode($tag), $base);
                        $return[] = '<a href="'.$url.'">'.e($tag).'</a>';
                    }
                    return $return;
                }

                /**
                 * Return next post after this one or null
                 *
                 * @param Tag $tag
                 * @return Post
                 */
                public function newerPost(Tag $tag = null)  //                 //here newVideo v_index & v_post
                {
                    $query =
                        static::where('published_at', '>', $this->published_at)
                            ->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
                            ->where('is_draft', 0)
                            ->orderBy('published_at', 'asc');
                    if ($tag) {
                        $query = $query->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tag) {
                            $q->where('tag', '=', $tag->tag);
                        });
                    }

                    return $query->first();
                }

                /**
                 * Return older post before this one or null
                 *
                 * @param Tag $tag
                 * @return Post
                 */
                public function olderPost(Tag $tag = null) //                 //here olderVideo v_index & v_post
                {
                    $query =
                        static::where('published_at', '<', $this->published_at)
                            ->where('is_draft', 0)
                            ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc');
                    if ($tag) {
                        $query = $query->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tag) {
                            $q->where('tag', '=', $tag->tag);
                        });
                    }

                    return $query->first();
                }
            }
```

this is my video table

```
    <?php

        use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
        use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

        class CreateVideosTable extends Migration
        {
            /**
             * Run the migrations.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function up()
            {
                Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->string('slug')->unique();
                    $table->string('v_title');
                    $table->string('v_subtitle');
                    $table->text('content_raw');
                    $table->text('content_html');
                    $table->string('page_image');
                    $table->string('meta_description');
                    $table->boolean('is_draft');
                    $table->string('layout')
                        ->default('blog.layouts.post');
                    $table->timestamps();
                    $table->timestamp('published_at')->index();
                });
            }

            /**
             * Reverse the migrations.
             */
            public function down()
            {
                Schema::drop('videos');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you did not refactor `title` to `v_title` in the whole class. For example, you should change

```
public function setTitleAttribute($value)
                {
                    $this->attributes['title'] = $value;

                    if (! $this->exists) {
                        $this->setUniqueSlug($value, '');
                    }
                }
```

to

```
public function setVTitleAttribute($value)
                {
                    $this->attributes['v_title'] = $value;

                    if (! $this->exists) {
                        $this->setUniqueSlug($value, '');
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

After you changed the column names, your dynamic setters **setTitleAttribute** and **setSubtitleAttribute** are not called and the slug does not get updated. You need to change the names of setter methods as well.

```
public function setVTitleAttribute($value) {
  ...
}

public function setVSubtitleAttribute($value) {
  ...
}
```